# Speech recognition problem in react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, speech-recognition

I have a problem with a library react-speech-recognition .
newcontent is a state when modify this state inside useeffect
print undefined
and I also want modify this state for transcript
also print undefined

```
const Room = () => {
let{
    transcript,
  } = useSpeechRecognition();
 
  const [newContent,setnewcontent]=useState('')
}
console.log(transcript)-->//here successful
 useEffect(() => {
console.log(transcript)-->//here undefined
    setnewcontent(transcript)  
console.log(setnewcontent)-->//here undefined  
},[])
```

Comment: `const [newContent,setnewcontent]=useState('')` needs to be `const [newContent,setnewcontent]=useState();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 separate `useEffect`. One to update the state and other to keep track on it and do the `console.log` as follows.

```
// This useEffect will trigger if any change detected in transcript variable
useEffect(() => {
    setnewcontent(transcript)    
},[transcript])

// This useEffect will trigger if any change detected in newContent state
useEffect(() => { 
    console.log(newContent)
},[newContent])
```